# How did Morgiana get her Household Vessel?

Tags: magi

Alibaba got Amon from a dungeon capturing a Djinn, yet Morgiana was able to get some sort of relative to Amon from within the dungeon of Zagan.

How does this work? I don't think they explained this anywhere.

Note: I haven't read any of the manga, which might be where the answers lie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Alibaba got Amon from a Dungeon, his sword became a **Metal Vessel**, because Amon moved inside Alibaba's sword after he completed the dungeon. In other words, Alibaba became a *Dungeon Capturer*.

> Dungeon Capturer (迷宮攻略者, Danjon Kōryakusha) is a person who
>   “completes” or “clears” Dungeons. If they survive the Dungeon, most of
>   the time that person acquires wealth and magical items, like a flying
>   cloth or Djinn Metal Vessel.

But Morgiana has a **Household Vessel**. Because Morgiana isn't a *Dungeon Capturer* she is a *Household Member*.

> Household Members are people who help a King Vessel capture Dungeons
>   and forms a Household Vessel from that person's Djinn, or if they form
>   a strong connection to the King Vessel. If the King Vessel does not
>   have his/her Metal Vessel, the assistant can not use their Household
>   Vessel

So, Morgiana was at the Dungeon when Alibaba got Amon and his **Metal Vessel**, then Morgiana made a connection to Alibaba's Amon. After this connection, was necessary an **activation**, and this only happened when they were at the dungeon of Zagan.

[Here](http://magi.wikia.com/wiki/Household_Members) is the list of all *Dungeon Capturer* and their respective *Household Members*.